# SQLAlchemy df.to_sql MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to move data from a database I own to a database I only have read/write permissions on (as a temp table). However, I get an error. Please see the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

con = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYServer;Database=DB_People;Trusted_Connection=yes;)

sSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_People;"

df = pd.read_sql(sSQL, con)

con.close()

con = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=NOT_MyServer;Database=DB_People;Trusted_Connection=yes;)

sSQL = "CREATE TABLE [##People Table] (p_Name varchar(25), p_DOB char(10));"

con.execute(sSQL)

con.committ()

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://NOT_MyServer/DB_People?Driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')

df.to_sql("##People Table")
```

I get the error:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any clues as to what the issue is? I specified a Driver in my connection and I know the Temp table exists because when I connect via SSMS I can query the table (although there are no records at this point.

I

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if I have found the problem(s):

1. The "Create Table" function is unneeded as the df.to_sql creates the table
2. Instead of the "+" in the Driver name, I was able to replace them with %20

This worked for me.